# secure hbase application - kerberos authentication

Tags: security, hbase, kerberos, keytab

I am running a infinite loop for testing expiration of kerberos credentials, I have the following code.

```
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(user, keytablocn);
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HConnection conn = HConnectionManager.createConnection(config);

for (;;) {
HTableInterface ht = conn.getTable(tableName);
getAndPriintRow(rowkey);
}
```

I expect the kerberos credentials to expire about 10 hrs after the program starts (a kinit on the linux shell using keytab requires relogin after about 10hrs in our environment).

However what I see in the log after about 10 hrs is:

> 15/03/06 12:39:54 DEBUG
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction
>   as:***(auth:KERBEROS)
>   from:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(RpcClient.java:796)
>   15/03/06 12:39:54 DEBUG
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: Initiating logout for
>   *** 15/03/06 12:39:54 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop logout
>   15/03/06 12:39:54 DEBUG
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: Initiating re-login
>   for *** 15/03/06 12:39:55 DEBUG
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login

The checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab() method was somehow invoked. I cant figure out how this method got invoked. This allows the program to run perpetually. Is this by design and what does the relogin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as per design. When session expires it will try to relogin.
This functionality enables HBase client's to stay up for eternity when they are used in Application Servers.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is this design documented anywhere, the javadocs certainly do not mention this one. Adding to that the existence of public methods that do a relogin made me think that I have to create a background thread to do the relogin every time

Comment: AFAIK, this feature of relogin/renew is part of standard Java security library. Your kerberos environment also has settings to allow relogin/renew a session. Hence, HBase docs might not be talking about it.